# Create a vocabulary with pos

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, part-of-speech

I would like to create a list of semantic entities (nouns, verbs, punct, etc.) using pos tagging.
I am currently running the following code

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
    
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])

def fun(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    pos = ""
    for token in doc:
        pos += token.pos_ + " "
    return pos

df['S']= df.Text.apply(fun)
```

to create the structure of sentences.
So, for example, if I have the column Text (see below), this code generate the column S which contains all the information about semantic structure:

```
Text                                                S
0   “I will meet quite a few people, it’s well...   PUNCT NOUN VERB VERB DET DET ADJ NOUN PUNCT PR...
1   Says “Cristiano Ronaldo’s family still owns”... VERB PUNCT PROPN PROPN PART NOUN ADV VERB PUNC...
2   Joe Biden plagiarized Donald Trump in his... PROPN PROPN VERB PROPN PROPN ADP DET PROP...
```

I am wondering if I can create a vocabulary of nouns, verbs, det, adj, ... by editing the code above or if I need to consider a different approach.
To take all the entities (nouns, verbs,...) in the dataframe, I would look at selecting only unique values, in order to creat a list for each of them.

Example of output (it can be also in lists rather than in a dataframe)

```
PUNCT      NOUN        VERB         ....
“           I          will 
,          people      meet
”          family      says
                       owns
                      plagiarized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])

texts = ['"I will meet quite a few people, it\'s well', 
         'Says "Cristiano Ronaldo\'s family still owns"',
         'Joe Biden plagiarized Donald Trump in his...']

df = pd.DataFrame({"Text":texts})

d = dict()
def func(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.pos_ not in d:
            d[tok.pos_] = [tok.text]
        else:
            d[tok.pos_].append(tok.text)
            
df.Text.apply(func)

pprint(d)
```

---

```
{'ADJ': ['few'],
 'ADP': ['in'],
 'ADV': ['well', 'still'],
 'AUX': ["'s"],
 'DET': ['quite', 'a', 'his'],
 'NOUN': ['people', 'family'],
 'PART': ["'s"],
 'PRON': ['I', 'it'],
 'PROPN': ['Cristiano', 'Ronaldo', 'Joe', 'Biden', 'Donald', 'Trump'],
 'PUNCT': ['"', ',', '"', '"', '...'],
 'VERB': ['will', 'meet', 'Says', 'owns', 'plagiarized']}
```

Note, you don't need pandas dependence at all:

```
docs = nlp.pipe(texts)
d = dict()
for doc in docs:
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.pos_ not in d:
            d[tok.pos_] = [tok.text]
        else:
            d[tok.pos_].append(tok.text)
pprint(d)
```

---

```
{'ADJ': ['few'],
 'ADP': ['in'],
 'ADV': ['well', 'still'],
 'AUX': ["'s"],
 'DET': ['quite', 'a', 'his'],
 'NOUN': ['people', 'family'],
 'PART': ["'s"],
 'PRON': ['I', 'it'],
 'PROPN': ['Cristiano', 'Ronaldo', 'Joe', 'Biden', 'Donald', 'Trump'],
 'PUNCT': ['"', ',', '"', '"', '...'],
 'VERB': ['will', 'meet', 'Says', 'owns', 'plagiarized']}
```

These will collect all the tokens under their `POS`.

If you only need list of unique tokens:

```
texts = ['"I will will meet quite a few people, it\'s well', 
         'Says "Cristiano Ronaldo\'s family still owns"',
         'Joe Biden plagiarized Donald Trump in his...']

docs = nlp.pipe(texts)
d = dict()
for doc in docs:
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.pos_ not in d:
            d[tok.pos_] = [tok.text]
        elif tok.text not in d[tok.pos_]:
            d[tok.pos_].append(tok.text)
pprint(d)
```

---

```
{'ADJ': ['few'],
 'ADP': ['in'],
 'ADV': ['well', 'still'],
 'AUX': ["'s"],
 'DET': ['quite', 'a', 'his'],
 'NOUN': ['people', 'family'],
 'PART': ["'s"],
 'PRON': ['I', 'it'],
 'PROPN': ['Cristiano', 'Ronaldo', 'Joe', 'Biden', 'Donald', 'Trump'],
 'PUNCT': ['"', ',', '...'],
 'VERB': ['will', 'meet', 'Says', 'owns', 'plagiarized']}
```